# No route matches when . character comes inside a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, urlencode

I have a route like this:

```
match '/pages/:name/preview' =>  'pages#page_preview'
```

But, it is giving me an error 'No route matches', when a route like this comes `/pages/a.com/preview`. I tried URL encoding the . character to `%2E`, but then also, the same error comes. I have also setup resources on the pages (`resources :pages`) before defining the preview route.

The route is working fine for all other routes, which do not have `.` character in the name parameter (space and ? etc are working fine)

Comment: :constraints => {:name => /[^\/]+/}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. To get out of this, add a constraint which overrides this.

```
match '/pages/:name/preview' =>  'pages#page_preview', :constraints => { :name => /[^\/]+/ }
```

This will allows anything except a slash.